# Spring Impersonation SwitchUserFilter Not Working | Filter is not adding to spring security chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

[SwitchUserFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.html) Hybris 5.7

I am trying to integrate impersonation functionality in Hybris 5.7. Here is the follow configuration i have done so far.

**spring-security-config.xml**

```
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true"  request-matcher-ref="excludeUrlRequestMatcher" use-expressions="true">

    <!-- added customer filter to security chain -->
    <security:custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />

</security:http>

<bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="originalUidUserDetailsService" />
    <property name="switchUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_switch_user" />
    <property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />
    <property name="targetUrl" value="/" />
</bean>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>switchUserProcessingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>switchUserProcessingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_switch_user</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now whenever I am login and trying to switch to another user say user@xyz.com, I am getting **NullPointerException.**

`https://localhost:9002/store/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=user@xyz.com`

Error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.attemptSwitchUser(SwitchUserFilter.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.training.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried to extend SwitchUserFilter and debug it. I found that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` is giving **null** thats why request is failing.

I also have seen a very wired situation. I have extend `SwitchUserFilter` and add my own service to write custom code but i can't able to `@Autowire` it.

I also tried to set Authentication in session while login with user. but the same session attribute i can't find in my extended SwitchUserFilter.

In the above code I am adding filter to security filter chain as well.

`<security:custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />`

Seems SwitchUserFilter does't know anything what session is setting or authentication is saving. I don't understand why it is happening even though i have done the right configuration. I have checked other related questions as well but not able to fix it.

Please help me on this. Let me know if you want some more code to put.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other thread (which you deleted), don't define it in the web.xml!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is my filter in not binding in Spring Security Chain so rather than using `custom-filter` mapping, I inject my filter directly to the filter chain.

**spring-filter-config.xml**

```
<alias name="defaultStorefrontTenantDefaultFilterChainList" alias="storefrontTenantDefaultFilterChainList" />
<util:list id="defaultStorefrontTenantDefaultFilterChainList">

// Other filter chain

   <ref bean="switchUserProcessingFilter"/> //Added my filter here
</util:list>
```

and simply added `switchUserProcessingFilter`in spring-security-config.xml

So there is no use to write filter-mapping in web.xml file and custom-filter in security-config.xml file.